# Make Eclipse indexer ignore "syntax error" on far pointer

Tags: c, macros, syntax-error, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse CDT with some code made for a compiler which accepts `near` and `far` pointers. However, Eclipse's indexer doesn't accept those keywords and returns a syntax error, disabling indexing on all declarations using `far` or `near`.

I tried adding a symbol in `Project/Preferences/C++ General/Paths and symbols\Symbols` (as suggested [on Eclipse's forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/72375/)), but even rebuilding the index the syntax error remains. Is there some step I'm missing or something else I could try?

I could add a macro to comment out these symbols, but I don't want to leave traces and would like to just make Eclipse's indexer accept or ignore them.

Comment: Sometimes, using `Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> Entries -> [Language] - >CDT User Setting Entries` to define the symbol works better than `Paths and Symbols`.

Comment: If that doesn't work either, please provide example code, and details about what symbol you are definining / where / to what value.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and report back